# tableView.datasource = self error:unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

When I describe `tableView.datasource = self`,
the app abend with `signal SIGABRT(unrecognized selector sent to instance)`.

When I erase `tableView.datasource = self`,
the app run but datasource method(`cellForRowInSection` etc) is not be reflected.

To manage the `tableView`, I use a `UIViewController` subclass.
The view is composed of multiple subviews, only one of which is a `tableView`.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

ViewController.m

```
    @interface ViewController ()
    @property (retain, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;
    @end
    @implementation ViewController{
      @private NSArray *_data1;
    @synthesize tableView = _tableView;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
      _tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-10, 70, 320, 480)];
      _tableView.dataSource = self;
      _tableView.delegate = self;
      [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
      return [_data1 count];
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
      return [_data1[section] count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
      if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      }
      NSString *data;
      data = _data1[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
      cell.textLabel.text = data;
      return cell;
    }
```

ERROR MESSAGE---------

when `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`
`return 1;`

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.23/UITableView.m:5261

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard’
```

when `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`
`return [_data1[section]count]`

```
[__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100006930
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100006930'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Update your question with the complete error.

Comment: Could you please write what is the unrecognized selector ?
Is is `count` ? I bet a kinder on it

Comment: FYI - get rid of the call to `@synthesize` - it is not needed. Also get rid of the call to `@private`. Any ivars in the `@implementation` block are already private.

Comment: Given the error, this means that `_data1[section]` is not an array, it is a string.

Comment: >rmaddy you were right._data1[section] is not an array.thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing this sample code, I think that the error can be that `_data1[section]` is not an object that is able to use the selector `count`.

When you remove the ligne `_tableView.dataSource = self;` the method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is not called and your app does not crash.

Comment: Exactly when `numberOfRowInSection{return 0;}`,the app does not crash.

Comment: @TeruyaKusumoto Then take a look at what you add in _data1, by looking at your `tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath:` it should be an array of array of string but it seems to be just an array of string.
For the crash you have when you use `return 1` try to use `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]` instead of `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]`

Comment: @TeruyaKusumoto It seems that your error was indeed that _data1[section] is not an array (can't use `count`), then remember to accept my answer :). Thx

Answer (score 0):

When you set your view controller as the datasource for the table view, your view controller must then conform to the UITableViewDataSource protocol.

There are 2 required methods in that protocol:

– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:  required method
– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:  required method

There are also a number of optional methods, including

– numberOfSectionsInTableView:
– sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:
– tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:
– tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:
– tableView:titleForFooterInSection:

If you don't at least implement the 2 required methods, your program will crash.

As the others have requested, you need to copy and paste the exact error message you are getting. That will help us understand what's going wrong.

Comment: thank you for answer.I pasted error message.Could you give me further answer?

Comment: Please accept the answer then, and come back and up vote it when you have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: If neither of the answers provided solved your problem and you solved it on your own, then please answer the question yourself. Then accept the answer that solved your problem. that way the question doesn't stay open. If one of the existing answers solved your problem, accept THAT. If you don't accept answers or post a solution that you find your self, people will start ignoring your questions after a while.